# Matching vectors in separate layers in QGIS. Overlay Question?

Tags: qgis, vector

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question since I do not know the term I need to use for this. I am planning driving routes to cover an entire state's road system. I already have a driving routes vector layer I have been creating and a state roads vector layer that includes all roads I need to cover. I need to know which roads have not been driven...Which state roads have not been traced over with my driving routes?

Overlay? Intersect? Join?

Comment: I think I want the Symmetrical Difference but the routes do not exactly match the road lines so would I need to spatially join them somehow?

Comment: I think the **Difference** tool might be the one you need.